# Multidimensional array in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**My Jquery code**

```
      var attrid        = [];
      var attrvalue     = [];

      $.each($(".attname1"), function(index){      

       if($('.getval'+index+'').val() != undefined){

          attrid.push($('.getval'+index+'').attr("id"));
          attrvalue.push($('.getval'+index+'').val());                  
        }

     });

    //outcome data
    ["5931", "5950", "5951", "5952"]  //id

    ["cas", "bsd", "Canvas", "Grey"] //name
```

**The result format that I actually want:**

```
$ary = array (
              [0] => array(
                      Id => 5931,
                      value=> cas,
                     ),
              [1] => array(
                      Id => 5950,
                      value=> bsd,
                     ),
              [2] => array(
                      Id => 5951,
                      value=> Canvas,
                     ),
              [3] => array(
                      Id => 5952,
                      value=> Grey,
                     )
       );
```

**Question:**

Above code are using Jquery to loop the data and store into array, I'm trying to create loop to create the result format the I want, but I failed to do that,anyone can provide me some sample code or idea which is can using Jquery to create the results format that I provided.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one array and push objects onto it:

```
var ary = [];
$('.attname1').each(function(index) {
    var getval = $('.getval' + index);
    if (getval.val()) {
        ary.push({
            id: getval.attr('id'),
            value: getval.val()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer :)